# Google indexed pictures or content

Tags: google-search

is it possible to remove content which is indexed in google? sorry if i am asking the question in wrong forum, let me know where to ask this otherwise.

some pictures of mine and certain statuses are indexed when searched in google and appears in top, so would like to know a way to get rid of this.

Comment: This isn't a security question; it is a question which could be answered with a google search.

Comment: While this question could be construed to be on-topic since it touches on privacy, it is specific to one web service and would be better served on [webapps.se].

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace *unless* the answer was **removed**!

Comment: It is a privacy question, as far as I know privacy is part of infosec. The question may not be written properly (and being new-ish on SE I wouldn't know so well) but I don't see why it wouldn't warrant an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, it's possible if you are a EU citizen to ask Google to stop linking your name to specific content. This is due to the very recently passed legislation on the [Right to be Forgotten](http://ec.europa.eu/justice/data-protection/).

If you're not a EU citizen, it's unlikely that your country (yet) provides such a right. I haven't heard of any other.

Note that search engines will only remove the results for searches made with your name, and not entirely remove the results from the Internet, to balance the right to be forgotten with the right to inform and freedom of expression.

Fill in the form [here for Google](https://support.google.com/legal/contact/lr_eudpa?product=websearch). And [here for Bing](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/tools/eu-privacy-request).